# HTML5 AppCache: Browser Refresh Not Working

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I'm struggling to get offline files working in Chrome.  The first view of the offline page works well, but if I refresh the browser, not so much.

Here's the manifest file (which IS being served as content type "text/cache-manifest"):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
../CSS/test.css
```

And here's the HTML for the page that I would like to function offline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/appname/Resources/manifest.appcache">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/test.css" />
</head>
<body>foo</body>
</html>
```

When the offline page loads for the FIRST time, I see in the Chrome Developer Tools console that the file in the manifest is loaded into appcache without any errors which is good.  However, when I try to refresh the browser, I see an HTTP GET error in the console, and the page doesn't have the styling from test.css applied to it.

What am I doing wrong?  If I look at the Resources tab in the developer tools, I see that the manifest file, the html file and the test.css file appear in the appcache.  When I refresh, Fiddler shows that the manifest file is being returned with an HTTP code of 304 which I guess would be expected?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Could you give the structure of your app (which files in which directories) ?

Comment: appname/Resources/manifest.appcache, appname/CSS/test.css, appname/HTML/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change the reference to the manifest from /appname/Resources/manifest.appcache to ../Resources/manifest.appcache.  I don't know why the initial call to the manifest would succeed and subsequent would fail with the former path, but the latter path seems to work.